# Someone is deleting my comments

Tags: discussion, comments

... for no other reason than that they are mine, or so it seems. I must have offended them. This makes it pointless to go on contributing, so if it's actually a technical problem, please let me know.

Comment: Since the comments have been deleted, we can't know what those were other than the flaggers/mods. You're free to quote what comments have been deleted by [edit]ing the question if you feel those comments shouldn't be deleted. Otherwise, we can only speculate either [they shouldn't be posted as comments in the first place](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), or [they are offensive enough](https://ell.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: They were fine - will unsubscribe from the forum.

Answer (score 7):

You have one answer, no questions and 215 comments. Comments are ephemeral and should be used primarily to ask authors for clarification of their posts. If you would like an answer to stick around, type in the answer box where your contributions can be properly scored and discussed by the community, and where you can update them based on that feedback.

Yours are not the only comments that have been removed. In 2018 [moderators removed about 11k comments and the community over 6K](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/2018-a-year-in-moderation). Other sites may be more lenient about comments, but they don’t have the same challenges that we do.

See this discussion for more detail : [Comments are constantly disappearing](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4800/9161)

The entire discussion is worth reading, but I’ll repeat part of one of my comments from that discussion that seems relevant:

> I know if you look at it from the perspective of an individual user, the comment policy seems harsh. If you look at it from the perspective of what is good for the site, it makes more sense. Information left in comments is pretty much useless from a site perspective. That content isn’t easily searchable, so it doesn’t help anyone who doesn’t stumble across it. It also prevents some people who may have also thought the same thing from including it in an answer where it belongs because they don’t want to “steal” it from whoever posted it first.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of "Why was my comment deleted?" questions, because no matter the comment, the answer is inevitably: *The mod team tries to keep the site tidy and civil. Flags get raised and we investigate. There are many reasons a comment might be deleted: tone, how many other comments are present, likely long-term usefulness, etc. Sometimes, in borderline cases, we simply make a judgment call*. I like what one SE meta answer said: _"In general, don't get too attached to comments. They are meant to be temporary, and can get cleaned up at any time."_

Answer (score 0):

To add a brief addendum to CollenV's answer:  If you choose to comment, rather than answer, then the comment is either not serious or mostly irrelevant.  Or, conversely, if you really think your comment was important enough to retain, then you should have put it into an answer.

Of course, this also means you have to substantiate what you say, and expose it to public vote.  You have to weigh the options.

Comment: I think it is patently unfair to leave answer-comments in a privileged place above answers that can be voted on. It is especially unfair when the person leaving them is only able to comment because of their association bonus and isn’t contributing any answers or questions at all. Frankly I hope that moderating comments more strictly will not only push people to consider leaving an answer, but also help them recognize the value of voting and do more of it.