# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on English Language Learners over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  31         29
Users destroyed³                                 241          0
Users deleted                                     40          0
Users contacted                                   40          0
User banned from review                            1          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            177      3,193
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue               104        605
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue           1      1,921
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               241        960
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                 22      4,764
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               346      7,053
Tags merged                                        4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              4          0
Tag synonyms created                               4          2
Revisions redacted                                 4          0
Questions unprotected                              6          0
Questions reopened                               137          7
Questions protected                               27        114
Questions migrated                                12          5
Questions merged                                   6          0
Questions flagged⁵                                20        984
Questions closed                               1,402      1,013
Question flags handled⁵                          360        639
Posts unlocked                                    11          2
Posts undeleted                                   59        192
Posts locked                                       5        310
Posts deleted⁶                                 1,523      4,572
Posts bumped                                       0      8,619
Escalations to the Community Manager team          2          0
Comments undeleted                               461          0
Comments flagged                                   4      3,284
Comments deleted⁷                             11,775      6,983
Comment flags handled                            757      2,531
Answers flagged                                  124      3,272
Answer flags handled                           2,859        537
All comments on a post moved to chat              72          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Could we convince you to change that “wanna” to a “want to”? That would normally not be anything remarkable on any other site, but this discussion sitting right next to your post makes it a bit weird: [Tidying up "slovenly" usages in question text](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5135/9161)

Comment: Edit if it bugs you, @colleen

Comment: [Thank you, Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9)

Comment: @Col Who's the *we?* The writer and the (currently) single up-voter? I'd rather let people talk how they wanna talk. One person's "slovenly" is another's light, playful, intimate, etc. See p 7 "taste tyranny" here: http://www.cambridge.org/assets/linguistics/cgel/chap1.pdf

Comment: @JimReynolds If you have something to contribute to that other discussion, it belongs over there. I just saw the “wanna” juxtaposed with a discussion about a negative perception of that exact language and thought it might cause unnecessary angst. I was going to edit it out after Shog indicated he didn’t mind, but there’s a comment warning editors that the post is automatically updated, and I didn’t want to remove it and prevent the post from being updated over something so minor.